# Probability with union bound

Tags: probability

I got this question:

> Earth is 70% covered with water. NASA would like to place 3 antennas
>   on Earth in such a way that (a) The antennas are spread out to form a
>   triangle with each edge of length exactly 1000km. (b) All antennas lay
>   in water. Prove that there exists locations for the antennas on Earth
>   that will satisfy the required constraints. Hint: use the union bound
>   on a certain probabilistic event.

I tried to create two variables:
A = All the antennas are in the water.
B = All the antennas are 1000km apart.

Now I tried to prove that $P(A \cap B) > 0$. In order to do that I open it up:
$$P(A \cap B) = 1 - P(A^C \cup B^C) \ge 1 - (P(A^C) + P(B^C))$$

But $$P(A^C) = 1-P(A) = 1 - 0.7^3 = 0.657$$
$$P(B^C) = 1-P(B) = 1 - (\frac1{(\pi * Earth Radius)})^3 = 1 - (\frac1{\pi * 6371})^3 \approx 1$$

So I get 
$$P(A \cap B) = 1 - (P(A^C) + P(B^C)) \approx 1-0.657-1<0$$

What is wrong? Any idea how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider all possible placements of equilateral triangles (with side length 1000) placed on the globe. If none of these triangles have all three vertices in the water, then at least one out of every three points on the globe is on land. Is this possible given our assumptions regarding the percentage of water vs. land on Earth?

**Answer:** Assume that all antennas have been placed in a triangle as stated in the question.

$P(A) =$ probability antenna $A$ is in the water.

$P(B) =$ probability antenna $B$ is in the water.

$P(C) =$ probability antenna $C$ is in the water.
\begin{gather}
P(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 1 - (P(A^C) + P(B^C) + P(C^C))\\
P(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 1 - (0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3)\\
P(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 1 - (0.9)\\
P(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 0.1
\end{gather}
Since the probability that this occurs is greater than zero, it is possible.

Comment: How can I calculate it? Another hint please? :)

Comment: Additional explanation added.

Comment: I undrstand that, but how can I calculate it? (And how do you use the "Hint" in the question?)

Comment: The hint I gave was to give you more intuition regarding the problem, and was geared towards proof by contradiction rather than using the question's hint.